# Is it acceptable to base a physical theory on a philosophical idea?

Tags: soft-question, models

Are theories that are based on the philosophy acceptable in Physics?
If the theory is based on the philosophy that obtained from laboratory experiments, can it be accepted?

Comment: "Accepted" by whom? The thought experiments that were done in the early days of quantum mechanics were quite philosophical, and resulted in real experiments and well accepted physics theories. Can you clarify a bit more how that example does or doesn't relate to your question?

Comment: You can get the idea for a theory from any source, previous theories, philosophy, religion, drugs (this was a frequent source in recent decades), or something else. But to be successful, you must formulate the resulting hypothesis/theory in a quantitative language that makes some predictions about the phenomena in Nature and these predictions can't be true tautologically - there has to be something non-obvious about them. And these predictions have to agree with the empirical data. When they don't, the theory is killed. When they do, it is strengthened.

Comment: But I think this is a mistake in Physics. 
The mathematical formula to arrive at the truth,
This is wrong.
Truth disappears
math formulas play with US

Comment: *"Truth disappears math formulas play with US"* I in no way understood what you were trying to say there. But you have a misunderstanding. Math allows us to express ideas quantitatively. Using it as a language, we describe natural processes and make predictions. Without this quantitative expression, a theory provides no predictions and so it becomes useless to us

Comment: I am not denying the positive role of mathematics in physics
But what is,
It is
In pure mathematics, we use to achieve the scientific facts
This is a quantum physicist wrong

Comment: How do you know for sure that is a quantum physicist wrong? many times, the experiments show for this, that is a quantum physicist right and sometimes that is a philosopher wrong

Comment: I have a question for you:
Why are so misled quantum physics
In telling the scientific facts
For example:
Dual behavior of light,
Lack of understanding of black holes,
Or even lack of understanding of the nature of power,
What power does?
Is quantum physicists have been able to show a clear picture of the force?
Do obvious phenomena have to hide behind  mathematical formula?

Answer (score 5):

If a theory is not built on a solid foundation of (semi-rigorous) mathematics and a well-defined *physical* idea, the chances of it being accepted by the majority of physicists as a valid physical model are extremely small. If one wants to build up a theory of physics *purely* from philosphy, one will into some significant problems. [After all is said and done, a theory *must* come up with some quantitative predictions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132566/why-should-any-physicist-know-to-some-degree-experimental-physics/132568#132568) for it to be any good.

However, this is not to say that philosophy has no role or place in physics. In fact, I think that the currently reasonably popular view that philosophy has nothing useful to contribute to physics is not only a philosophical statement in and of itself (and therefore immediately inconsistent) but also *false*. Whether we like it or not, physicists, too, are humans. When we think about theories and models of physical phenomena, it is really inevitable that our ideas, judgments and inspirations are partially due to things that are not strictly objective or scientific. This is not a problem and there is no need to hide it, but it is really unreasonable to *deny* it

One example that I think demonstrates my point quite well is the modern perspective of all physical theories as *effective* theories that should not expected to be absolutely true, but just capture the essential phenomena at some relevant (energy) scale of interest. Another example that is already being pointed out by Floris is the development of quantum mechanics (and relativity theory) in the early 20th century, which heavily relied on thought experiments that were often quite philosophical in nature.

Comment: But if the philosophical theory is consistent with laboratory experiments
The chances of acceptance is low?

Comment: @hadi The point is that, with pure philosophy, you will *never* be able to get quantitative agreement with experiments. For that, you need to do some calculations.

Comment: You are right. But the point is that
Mathematics expressed phenomenon Details
Facts phenomena is something else
Is easily explained by the philosophy

Comment: @hadi sorry, but I couldn't understand that sentence. Could you try to improve the grammar to make it more understandable?

Comment: @hadi Perhaps, but if it is easily explained by philosophy, then it usually is also easy to express mathematically. We express things in as many ways as we can so that we have as many opportunities as we can get to notice new things and make new connections. That means philosophy alone is not sufficient

Answer (score 4):

If a theory never connects with experimental reality then no matter how neat it is it will eventually be dropped. This is the problem that much of theoretical physics based around the various incarnations of String Theory finds itself.

A theory is in one very real sense a data compression and predictive algorithm. It needs to join the experimental dots in the most efficient manner and also tell people where other dots might be found. Whether those "dots" are joined in a manner that creates a picture understandable by Humans seems (at present) to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

> Are theories that are based on the philosophy acceptable in Physics?

Sure, but only if backed by maths and experiment. The prime example would be General Relativity, the development of which was guided by a whole bunch of principles (Mach's principle, equivalence principle, principle of covariance).

In contrast, Einstein failed to develop a unified classical field theory, arguably because there was no new guiding principle and he ended up just toying with the mathematics. (Note that Einstein actually did end up with a candidate theory that he hadn't discarded as of his death).

String theory as of today is probably in better shape than classical unification was back then, but it hasn't been universally accepted precisely because the most important ingredient besides philosophy and mathematics is still missing: experimental verification.